# user_register not triggering with email verification

Tags: plugin-development, user-registration, email-verification

I have a multisite installation and my custom functions hooked on `user_register` or `wpmu_activate_user` are not triggering when the "**send verification email option**" is **enabled**. Curiously, when inserting directly without asking for mail confirmation all the hooks trigger just fine. Any ideas why?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [developer documentation of `wpmu_activate_user` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wpmu_activate_user/), **it fires immediately after a new user is activated**. That means it happens after a user activates their account.

The same is happening for `user_register`. It is firing when **a new user added to the database**. It is not happening until a user activates the account. Check [this documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) about `user_register` hook.

In your case, the [`after_signup_user`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_signup_user/) hook could be helpful.